# Upgrading to Chromedriver 76 causing alerts to auto dismiss

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was using Chrome driver version 74 before and chrome browser version 74. There were no issues with alerts during that time. When my browser got auto updated to version 76, I did replace Chrome driver version to 76.

When i ran the same scripts after updating, alerts on my browser started auto dismissing when it runs below code (code snippet of wait.py in selenium ). I did retest the same code on different PC with driver 74 and browser 74 and it worked fine.

I suspected chrome changed alert behavior in latest drivers and tried to use
following statement in chrome driver options but did not work.
     "profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups":0,

Popup is getting dismissed at line "value = method(self._driver)" of the below code.

```
def until(self, method, message=''):
    """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
    return value is not False."""
    screen = None
    stacktrace = None

    end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
    while True:
        try:
            value = method(self._driver)
            if value:
                return value
        except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
            screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
            stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
        time.sleep(self._poll)
        if time.time() > end_time:
            break
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

chromeoptions used:

```
  self._chromeoptions = Options
    self._chromeops = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": mainpath + r"\bin\download_files",
             "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
             "download.prompt_for_download": False,
             'credentials_enable_service': False,
             'profile': {
                 'password_manager_enabled': False
             },
             "applicationCacheEnabled": True,
             "safebrowsing": {"enabled": True, "malware": {"enabled": True}}}
    self._caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    self._chromeops.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    self._caps.setdefault("pageLoadStrategy", "normal")
    self._chromeops.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors", "enable-automation"])
    self._chromeops.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    self._chromeops.add_argument("--disable-plugins")
    self._chromeops.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    self._chromeops.set_capability('unexpectedAlertBehaviour', "ignore")
    self._chromeops.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
```

Additional details:

Method calling function until...

```
         def wait_till_inactive_delay(self, xpath, delay=20):
             xpath = self.generate_xpath_structure(xpath)
             WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay, ignored_exceptions=    [NoSuchElementException]).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

With old chromedriver, when there is alert and above fucntion is invoked it would ignore and proceed but now when there is alert open in browser and above method is called then alert is getting dismissed.

I am expecting chrome browser / driver to allow user to accept popup using switch_to_alert.accpet() instead of it dismissing the popups.

Comment: Can you post the code that `method` is referring to? Seems as though something in that callback is dismissing the alert.

Comment: you might want to try using chromedriver v75... that works with chrome browser v76, too and it looks like they fixed a bug concerning alerts in v76 that may have changed some behavior here.

Comment: @pcalkins Tried with v75 but still the issue persists. I think there is something on browser end that got changed. V74 does not even open browser but v75,v76 does but alerts are getting auto dismissed

Comment: @GregBurghardt  "expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))" is the method that is being passed.

Comment: Can you post the line of code that is calling the `until` method, and add that to your question? This will give us some context.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Added additional details in question

Answer (score 3):

('unhandledPromptBehavior', "ignore")

Above desired capability ignored the popups

Comment: it looks like the default now is "dismiss and notify".  This happens when a certain action occurs and there is still a prompt waiting for a response.  I believe "ignore" will still throw an exception if the prompt has not been closed at that point.  (and any "and notify" options.  This is due to chromedriver supporting the W3C standard for WebDriver now.